# Trying to send an email via python with smtp protocol with no success

Tags: python, email, smtp

I know I have the built in lib "smtplib" in python, but I want to learn how to do it without it,
After reading about this protocol, I tried to fond a code sample shows how to do that via python, but I couldnt find any, so I built one myself, but with no success.
This is my code:

```
import socket

soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print "Connecting to smtp server of google by SSL..."
soc.connect(("smtp.gmail.com", 465))
print "Connected to smtp server of google by SSL!"

print "Sending helo to our friend..."
soc.send("HELO FromX")
print "'helo' went good!"

print "Announcing google about the Sender (us...)..."
soc.send("mail From: xxx@google.com")
print "I just announced google!"

print "Announcing google about the receiver (us...)..."
soc.send("RCPT To: xxx@gmail.com")
print "I just announced google!"

print "Ask google for sending him some data..."
soc.send("DATA")
print "Google accepted us... of course he is, we are handsome!"

print "Now the all other stuff..."
soc.send("From: xxx@gmail.com\nTo: xxx@gmail.com\nSubject: HEY\n\nBYE\n.")
soc.send("QUIT")

soc.close()
```

With that code, I got that sniff with Wireshark:
[The sniffed information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifxo0.png)

I will be happy to hear some help from you guys.
(Also, I wondered... shouldnt I commit some authentication to make google sure it is really me the messege sender?)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Python's built in module for SMPT [Python SMPT Lib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/smtplib.html)
and see this tutorial for more info about [Sending Emails with Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm)

**NOTE:** If you have 2FA you need to disable it before doing anything!

**Python 3**
Sample Code:

```
    import smtplib

    uname = "you@gmail.com"
    pword = "your_gmail_account_password"

    from = "you@gmail.com"
    to = "to@example.com"
    msg = "Hi There!"

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.login(uname,pword)

    s.sendmail(from,to,msg)
    print("Mail Send Successfully")
    s.quit()
```

Comment: I know I to use this library.. But I wrote explicitly I want to do it without it

Comment: Then try using an email service! You can't send emails via python like php with the builtin mail() function! You need to use an email service or SMPT!

Comment: prefer smtp.. tnx